# Regarding validation of the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box using input tag with the type number. Now sometimes if the user is entering the alphabet in the text box its just clearing the text box.I need to alert a error message when user is entering alphabet in the text box.

I tried using document.getElementById("idofTextbox").validity.valid,but it is giving true. So any suggestion or solution for this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to block user to enter alphabet in textbox?

Comment: user can enter anything but custom alert should be there when user enter alphabet in text box with type is number.

Comment: So why allow alphabet if you want only numbers...? See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/

Comment: @IdanAdar By giving input tag type as number. when alphabet is given in the text box , then it automatically clears it. I wanted to show a alert before clearing the text box stating 'Enter valid text'

Comment: can you host your code on fiddle to see this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you

```
var numberOnly = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$'); // RegEx
var inputVal = document.getElementById("id").value;
numberOnly.test(inputVal); // Returns true/false
```

Comment: As i have given type of the input tag as number , it will be cleared as soon as the function of the form is called. But i want to give alert before clearing the text box .

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<input type="text" name="First Name" id="first" placeholder="Enter number here"/>
$('#first').keyup(function(event){
    if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        alert("Enter only numbers");
    }
});
```

Working  [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/6505/)

Answer (score 0):

> Here "keyup-numeric" is a class of you input field.**Note** change your "input type='number' " to "input type='text' "

```
$('.keyup-numeric').keyup(function() {
    $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
    if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-1">Numeric characters only.</span>');
    }
});
```

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/kyntt30p/)